# Retrieve a SharePoint list data into a datatable in JSON format using asp.net web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint, datatable

I am trying to get data from a SharePoint list using asp.net web API MVC application, then load it to a datatable and finally give that as API output as JSON format.

I have tried to get the data from a SharePoint list, but SharePoint gives `null` as a result.

I am expecting the data to load to my data table and API should give that data as JSON output.

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Comment: Which SharePoint api did you use (CSOM/JSOM/SSOM)? Include your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question is not clear. Still, I Tried.

This is the code which i used in my console application.

```
public static SPListItemCollection GetCollection()
        {
            string listName = 'Your List Name';
            string queryStr = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title''/><Value Type='Text'>" + YourValue + "</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy>";
            SPListItemCollection oCollection = GetListItemCollectionByQuery(listName, queryStr);

            return oCollection;
        }

        public static SPListItemCollection GetListItemCollectionByQuery(string ListName, string queryText)
        {
            SPListItemCollection spListItemCollection = null;
            string webUrl = Your Site URL;
            try
            {
                using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(webUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        string listName = ListName;
                        SPList spList = oSPWeb.Lists[listName];

                        if (spList != null)
                        {
                            SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
                            spQuery.Query = queryText;
                            spListItemCollection = spList.GetItems(spQuery);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleException(ex);
            }
            return spListItemCollection;
        }
```

Also, you need to check this [Get DataTable](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180374/difference-between-splist-getdatatable-and-splist-getitemsspquery-getdatatable)

I hope it may help :)